# How to get all the content in the navbar on one line and centered

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar which uses CSS, HTML and jQuery. I am having trouble with the alignment of the contents. I want all of it in one line and to be centered.
Following is css for my code I am trying to center all the contents of navbar and trying to center the navbar itself but failing to do so.

```
   * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: none
    }
    body {
        background: #555;
    }
    header {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        background: #333;
    }
    .logo {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 123;
        padding: 10px;
        font: 18px verdana;
        color: #6DDB07;
        float: left;
        width: 15%
    }
    .logo a {
        color: #6DDB07;
    }
    nav {
        position: relative;
        width: 980px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #cssmenu,
    #cssmenu ul,
    #cssmenu ul li,
    #cssmenu ul li a,
    #cssmenu #head-mobile {
        border: 0;
        list-style: none;
        line-height: 1;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box
    }
    #cssmenu:after,
    #cssmenu > ul:after {
        content: ".";
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        visibility: hidden;
        line-height: 0;
        height: 0
    }
    #cssmenu #head-mobile {
        display: none
    }
    #cssmenu {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        background: #333
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li {
        float: left
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li > a {
        padding: 17px;
        font-size: 12px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ddd;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
    #cssmenu ul li.active a {
        color: #fff
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li:hover,
    #cssmenu ul li.active:hover,
    #cssmenu ul li.active,
    #cssmenu ul li.has-sub.active:hover {
        background: #448D00!important;
        -webkit-transition: background .3s ease;
        -ms-transition: background .3s ease;
        transition: background .3s ease;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
        padding-right: 30px
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 22px;
        right: 11px;
        width: 8px;
        height: 2px;
        display: block;
        background: #ddd;
        content: ''
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 19px;
        right: 14px;
        display: block;
        width: 2px;
        height: 8px;
        background: #ddd;
        content: '';
        -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
        transition: all .25s ease
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
        top: 23px;
        height: 0
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        left: -9999px
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li {
        height: 0;
        -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
        background: #333;
        transition: all .25s ease
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li:hover {} #cssmenu li:hover > ul {
        left: auto
    }
    #cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
        height: 35px
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul ul {
        margin-left: 100%;
        top: 0
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
        padding: 11px 15px;
        width: 170px;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ddd;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
    #cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
        border-bottom: 0
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
    #cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
        color: #fff
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 16px;
        right: 11px;
        width: 8px;
        height: 2px;
        display: block;
        background: #ddd;
        content: ''
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 13px;
        right: 14px;
        display: block;
        width: 2px;
        height: 8px;
        background: #ddd;
        content: '';
        -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
        transition: all .25s ease
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
        top: 17px;
        height: 0
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover,
    #cssmenu ul li.has-sub ul li.has-sub ul li:hover {
        background: #363636;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul ul li.active a {
        border-left: 1px solid #333
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a,
    #cssmenu > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active> a {
        border-top: 1px solid #333
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
        .logo {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 46px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px 0 0 0;
            float: none
        }
        .logo2 {
            display: none
        }
        nav {
            width: 100%;
        }
        #cssmenu {
            width: 100%
        }
        #cssmenu ul {
            width: 100%;
            display: none
        }
        #cssmenu ul li {
            width: 100%;
            border-top: 1px solid #444
        }
        #cssmenu ul li:hover {
            background: #363636;
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li,
        #cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
            height: auto
        }
        #cssmenu ul li a,
        #cssmenu ul ul li a {
            width: 100%;
            border-bottom: 0
        }
        #cssmenu > ul > li {
            float: none
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li a {
            padding-left: 25px
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li {
            background: #333!important;
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li:hover {
            background: #363636!important
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
            padding-left: 35px
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li a {
            color: #ddd;
            background: none
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
        #cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
            color: #fff
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul,
        #cssmenu ul ul ul {
            position: relative;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            text-align: left
        }
        #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
        #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
        #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
        #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before 
        {
            display: none
        }
        #cssmenu #head-mobile {
            display: block;
            padding: 23px;
            color: #ddd;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: 700
        }
        .button {
            width: 55px;
            height: 46px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 12399994;
        }
        .button:after {
            position: absolute;
            top: 22px;
            right: 20px;
            display: block;
            height: 4px;
            width: 20px;
            border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
            content: ''
        }
        .button:before {
            -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
            -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
            transition: all .3s ease;
            position: absolute;
            top: 16px;
            right: 20px;
            display: block;
            height: 2px;
            width: 20px;
            background: #ddd;
            content: ''
        }
        .button.menu-opened:after {
            -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
            -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
            transition: all .3s ease;
            top: 23px;
            border: 0;
            height: 2px;
            width: 19px;
            background: #fff;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg)
        }
        .button.menu-opened:before {
            top: 23px;
            background: #fff;
            width: 19px;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg)
        }
        #cssmenu .submenu-button {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 99;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            display: block;
            border-left: 1px solid #444;
            height: 46px;
            width: 46px;
            cursor: pointer
        }
        #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
            background: #262626
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button {
            height: 34px;
            width: 34px
        }
        #cssmenu .submenu-button:after {
            position: absolute;
            top: 22px;
            right: 19px;
            width: 8px;
            height: 2px;
            display: block;
            background: #ddd;
            content: ''
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after {
            top: 15px;
            right: 13px
        }
        #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
            background: #fff
        }
        #cssmenu .submenu-button:before {
            position: absolute;
            top: 19px;
            right: 22px;
            display: block;
            width: 2px;
            height: 8px;
            background: #ddd;
            content: ''
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before {
            top: 12px;
            right: 16px
        }
        #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
            display: none
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul ul li.active a {
            border-left: none
        }
        #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a,
        #cssmenu > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a {
            border-top: none
        }
```

The following is html for my code
my goal is to center my navbar on the screen. i would appreciate any kind of help!

```
<nav id='cssmenu'>
<div class="logo"><a href="#">something </a></div>
<div id="head-mobile"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>something</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>something</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">something</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">something</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">something</a>
<ul>
      <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li ><a href="#">something</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">something</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">something</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
<li><a href="#">something</a></li>

</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

View in Plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/YkuipAhi9a6rSqnKRMMv

Comment: I've just added a plunkr to your question, and if you view it full screen (expand to the full screen preview), the navbar is centered on the screen. I'm not sure what's not working - can you clarify? https://plnkr.co/edit/YkuipAhi9a6rSqnKRMMv

Comment: @StephenR.Smith i can't seem to locate the left and right padding i am getting in the navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nav has the following style applied:

```
nav {
    position: relative;
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Which is giving the entire nav div containing all your menu items a fixed width of 980px, and then setting the margin on the left and right to auto, effectively centering it on the screen. That's where what appears to be padding on the left and right side of the nav is coming from, it's actually auto margin.

If you want the menu to fill the screen, but the menu content to be centered, you can nest the menu in a separate div and style the outer container with the #333 fill, and make it 100% wide to make it fill the screen. I've modified the nav style and added the cssmenu.nav-container style:

```
nav {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: #333;
}

#cssmenu.nav-container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
}
```

Then changed the html:

```
<body>
<nav>
    <div class="nav-container" id='cssmenu'>
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#">something </a>
        </div>
        <div id="head-mobile">
        </div>
        <div class="button">
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>something</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>something</a> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">something</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a> </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">something</a> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">something</a> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">something</a> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">something</a> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</body>
```

Note that I've removed the cssmenu id from nav and added it to a nested div with a nav-container class. Nav gets the 100% width and grey fill, and the new nav-container gets the 980px fixed width and the auto margins, centering it on the screen.

Here's an updated Plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/U8yEQfqN2zcPWWyAZOsv

Answer (score 1):

All your li items in the nav are using float:left; property, to make them centered use this

CSS

```
#cssmenu > ul > li{
float:left; /*remove float*/
display:inline-block;
}

#cssmenu{
text-align:center;
}
```